# Select given "word" in Zsh currently being typed command line

Tags: zsh

In Zsh (non Vim editing mode) how can I repeat a given word on the currently being typed command? For example, I can extract all that was typed to this point with `!#`:

```sh
mv /example !#
```

Becomes

```sh
mv /example mv /example
```

But what I want is just the `/example`. E.g.

```sh
mv /example # <insert magic incantation here>
```

to become

```sh
mv /example /example
```

Which I can, in the above example, then carry on typing to rename something without flow-breaking text selection with trackpad or excessive back-and-forth command line editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the widget `copy-prev-shell-word` to some conveinient key combination, like `CTRL+W`:

```
bindkey '^W' copy-prev-shell-word
```

(Put this line into your `~/.zshrc` config file to make it permanent.)

This is the description from `man zshzle`:

> **copy-prev-shell-word** Like  copy-prev-word, but the word is found by using shell parsing, whereas copy-prev-word looks for blanks. This
> makes a difference when the word is quoted and contains spaces.